# Is the Power-Link designed for routine usage?

Tags: mountain-bike, chain, tools

I have a [Power-Link](http://www.bicycling.com/images/reviewfinder/0700powerlink.jpg) which i intended to use in emergencies (when the chain breaks and i'm far from home). Used it once, worked pretty well.

Now i wonder, what if i use it permanently with my chain? My idea is that it might be convenient to quickly remove the chain, stuff it into a bowl of acetone/oil/whatever, and easily install it back onto the bike.

But will the Power-Link wear out quickly (e.g. quicker than the other "links" of the chain)? I am not sure whether it was intended to be used all the time or just for emergencies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several versions of SRAMs power links. The original versions were intended for reuse, and you would have no problem using them in that manner. If you have an 8 or 9 speed bike, you've got one of the original designs.

If you have a ten speed SRAM drivetrain, then you need to look at the link and the model of the chain. SRAMs newest power links for 10 speed are not designed to be used more than once. They are sold in a 4 pack so that you have replacements to use.

The gold power link you've pictured is either 9 speed, or one of the first 10 speed links, which is reusable. If yours is black, you have one of the newer, non reusable variety.

If the chain is a PC-1071, PC-1091 or 1091r, this is the links it comes with, and while you can remove them, they need to be replaced with a fresh link each time you do.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I'll add that 9spd version works well with Shimano 9spd chains. 8spd doesn't, though.

Comment: By the way, the non-reusable links for 10 speed seem to be called "PowerLock", where the reuseable ones for 9 speed are called "PowerLink".

Answer (score 4):

It's intended for permanent use -- it's what SRAM provides for permanently joining their chains.  I've got several thousand miles on them, with no difficulties.